# Excel: Auto Duplicate workbook and based off list

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty new to VBA (total noob) and struggling hard, I've been cannibalizing bits of formula off various parts of the forum to get what I need and now I'm stuck.

Basically I have a workbook I need said workbook duplicating many times and for it to create the save name from a list here's what I have so far

```
Sub create()
Dim wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("List") 'Edit sheet name
Set sh2 = Sheets("Data") 'Edit sheet name
lr = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A1:A" & lr)

For Each c In rng
    Sheets("Template").Copy 'Edit sheet name
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = c.Value
    sh2.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
    wb.SaveAs c.Value & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close False
Next
End Sub
```

So List Is obviously my list of names for the files and it works well, however the workbook has more sheets other than "Data" and "Template" so if I had other sheets named "Data2" and "Data3" for instance how could I write them in to also be copied into the workbooks that are created.

Thank you in advance you wonderful people.

Alex

Comment: So to summarise you want your code to save your sheets as a separate individual workbook for each sheet?

Comment: @Calum No not quite at the moment if I add other sheets into the original workbook it won't add them into the workbooks the macro at the moment it only adds in my "template" and "data" tabs if I was to add further tabs i.e. "data2" writing:

     Set sh3 = Sheets("Data2") 'Edit sheet name

That doesn't work, if that makes sense. Sorry if it seems vague.

Comment: if that's all you want then keep with `Set sh3 = Sheets("Data2")` then after `sh2.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)` underneath add `sh3.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)` and do the same for each sheet.

Comment: Or you can use loops! Take a look at my answer! ;)

Comment: Yeah, loops would definently be the most efficient way, but considering he said he was totally new I just give the basics.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! @R3uk and Calum!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this one will be more efficient and easily editable than your initial version :

```
Sub create()
Dim WbSrc As Workbook, _
    WbDest As Workbook, _
    SheetToExport As String, _
    sh1 As Worksheet, _
    lr As Long, _
    rng As Range, _
    A() As String


Set WbSrc = ThisWorkbook
Set sh1 = WbSrc.Sheets("List") '----Edit sheet name
lr = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = sh1.Range("A1:A" & lr)

'----Add sheet's names here separated with /
'----They will be exported in the same order
SheetToExport = "Template/Data/Data2"
A = Split(SheetToExport, "/")

'----Make a new workbook with all the sheet you want to export
WbSrc.Sheets(A(0)).Copy
Set WbDest = ActiveWorkbook
For i = LBound(A) + 1 To UBound(A)
    WbSrc.Sheets(A(i)).Copy After:=WbDest.Sheets(WbDest.Sheets.Count)
Next i

'----Now that the base is good, change value in A1 and SaveAs
For Each c In rng
    WbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1") = c.Value
    Set WbDest = WbDest.SaveAs(c.Value & ".xlsx")
Next c

WbDest.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help! As you are new to SO, just a quick reminder of the basics : Once an answer solved your issue, please validate it with the tick right under up/down votes. And remember to use the up/down votes (once you have 15 reputation points) if you find any post useful/useless! ;) Enjoy SO!

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes late.
I'd write it like the code below.
Rather than state which sheets to copy in the code just add the sheet names in column A and TRUE in column B if you want it copied, then in another column add the file names you want to use.

Can use a formula to calculate how long your named range is - something like **=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))** to take all values in column A of sheet1.

```
Public Sub Create()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim rngFiles As Range
    Dim rngSheets As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim d As Range

    'Named ranges in your workbook.
    Set rngFiles = Range("FileNames")
    Set rngSheets = Range("SheetsToCopy")

    'Each file name
    For Each d In rngFiles
        Set wrkBk = Nothing

        'Check if each sheet is needed - 1 column to right of
        'sheet name states TRUE if you want the sheet copied.
        For Each c In rngSheets
            If c.Offset(, 1) = True Then

                If wrkBk Is Nothing Then
                    'Create a new workbook if one hasn't been created.
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(c.Value).Copy
                    Set wrkBk = ActiveWorkbook
                Else
                    'If workbook has been created then copy sheets to it.
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(c.Value).Copy _
                        After:=wrkBk.Sheets(1)
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        'Save the file and close it.
        wrkBk.SaveAs d.Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
        wrkBk.Close
    Next d

End Sub
```